# Xcode 10 fails to run XCTest/XCUITest on device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

After upgrading to XCode 10, it fails to run my tests on the device.
After finish building, it immediately shows a popup "Test Failed" without showing any errors on the console.

"Run" works on device. Both XCTest and XCUITest runs on simulator.

The error is reproducible on new project running the default UITest on the device.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the phone made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check Targets [Build Settings] Search IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET

Remove IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET setting

#### Before:

[image: Before]

#### After:

[image: After]

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: So that you know: It's generally frowned upon to post nearly identical answers on more than one question (in fact, doing so raises an automatic flag for moderators, in some cases). Usually, if an identical answer will work on another question, then it's likely that the questions should be considered duplicates and you should flag the question for closure as a duplicate, which is something you'll be able to do once you have 15 reputation points. If you are going to post very similar answers, then the answers should edited to be tailored to the question, even if they cover similar information.

Comment: Ok, I don't know much about the rules of use.
Thanks for suggestions